# When I try to run React boilerplate localhost I getting the error

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, reselect

Reference: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate

I have tried to run the project in localhost as per instructions, but the getting the below code any one could help me please

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ksche\Documents\Projects\React_BoilerPlate\into\new_Project\node_modules\pngquant-bin
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node lib/install.js
npm ERR! ‼ Command failed: C:\Users\ksche\Documents\Projects\React_BoilerPlate\into\new_Project\node_modules\pngquant-bin\vendor\pngquant.exe --version
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR!   ‼ pngquant pre-build test failed
npm ERR!   i compiling from source
npm ERR!   × Error: pngquant failed to build, make sure that libpng-dev is installed
npm ERR!     at C:\Users\ksche\Documents\Projects\React_BoilerPlate\into\new_Project\node_modules\execa\index.js:231:11
npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
npm ERR!     at async Promise.all (index 0)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ksche\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-08-15T14_41_21_036Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\ksche\Documents\Projects\React_BoilerPlate\into\new_Project> npm start

> react-boilerplate@4.0.0 start
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
throw err;
^

Error: Cannot find module 'express'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\ksche\Documents\Projects\React_BoilerPlate\into\new_Project\server\index.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object. (C:\Users\ksche\Documents\Projects\React_BoilerPlate\into\new_Project\server\index.js:3:17)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
  'C:\Users\ksche\Documents\Projects\React_BoilerPlate\into\new_Project\server\index.js'
  ]
  }

Answer (score 0):

It's likely express wasn't installed correctly.  try running `npm install express` in the terminal(you should be in the root folder of your project).

If you now run `express -v`, the version of express you have should be returned to you.

If not, verify you are in the correct directory for your project when entering the above commands, and try again.